# Display products for today, tomorrow, week and month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to display products for today and make such a request:

```
SELECT P.* FROM PRODUCTS AS P WHERE P.END_DATE>=NOW() AND P.STARTING_DATE <= NOW()::DATE
```

What would I bring products for tomorrow, I do + 1

```
SELECT P.* FROM PRODUCTS AS P WHERE P.END_DATE>=NOW() AND P.STARTING_DATE <= NOW()::DATE + 1
```

For the week + 7

```
SELECT P.* FROM PRODUCTS AS P WHERE P.END_DATE>=NOW() AND P.STARTING_DATE <= NOW()::DATE + 7
```

But how to withdraw for the current month?

If I do + 30, it displays in 3 days, but I do not need the product for the next month.

And do I fulfill the other requests correctly?

Comment: Don't know postgre but maybe there is something like "datepart"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INTERVAL`

For tomorrow ;

```
SELECT P.* FROM PRODUCTS AS P WHERE P.END_DATE>=NOW() AND P.STARTING_DATE <= NOW()::DATE  + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

For 1 week;

```
SELECT P.* FROM PRODUCTS AS P WHERE P.END_DATE>=NOW() AND P.STARTING_DATE <= NOW()::DATE  + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: I understand the course of your thoughts, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT P.*
FROM PRODUCTS P
WHERE P.END_DATE >= DATE_TRUNC('MON', CURRENT_DATE) AND 
      P.STARTING_DATE < DATE_TRUNC('MON', CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
```